# macOS "Mouse Keys" Change Bindings

Tags: macos, keyboard

I decided to try the "Mouse Keys" feature as documented [here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-the-pointer-using-mouse-keys-mh27469/mac) but I would prefer to bind the mouse controls to different keys.

Here are the defaults:
[image: Mouse Key Bindings]

Evidently, there aren't any first-party ways to do this. Are there *any* ways to change which keys bind to the mouse? (If it isn't immediately obvious, the other keys still work as input.)

Comment: "other keys still work as input" …actually, they don't. On a laptop if mousekeys is on, the rest of the keyboard essentially *isn't*. This is actually far more convenient to do on an extended keyboard, where the rest of it still does work as normal. Toggling it with 5xOpt is OK, but a bit tiresome to do on a laptop if you need to swap frequently.

Comment: @Tetsujin. Mouse Keys does not affect anything other than 789uiojkl on my iMac with a non-extended keyboard, and I know from answering questions in the Apple forums that plenty of users find only those keys are not working (and need to know the fix)

Comment: @TomGewecke -  Ah, OK, thanks. Point taken. The Apple KB is vague on that matter in that case & I've actually never used a Mac without an extended keyboard.